Packaging commercial python modules
I contribute to quite a few open-source projects but this is a question about managing closed source code.
I'm developing some python libraries which we'll use internally. Sometimes we might want to share some analysis codes but keep parts of it secrete.
Is there a good way to compile a module so it appears as a blackbox without access to the source?
Even better if we can allow the use of the black-box for a specified amount of time?

Another option is to deploy your code as a web service so that the customer never takes possession. Analysis code may fit the mold nicely. Perhaps a client is deployed to the customer and it interacts with a web based backend.
